Books with accompanied video lectures
I am currently studying Solow's How to Read and Write Proofs, which has been an excellent resource for improving my mathematical reasoning. The clear explanations and structured approach to proof-writing, along with the author's video lectures on the Wiley website and YouTube, enhance the learning experience.
I am now seeking recommendations for other mathematics books (particularly in algebra, analysis, and topology) that are similarly accompanied by video lectures, either by the author or by a professor, such as Benedict Gross’s lectures for Artin's Algebra.
Thank you very much for any suggestions (English and French books alike).
Wishing everyone a Happy New Year!

Axler has his Linear Algebra Done Right with videos on his site.

This is not related to a book, but perhaps it can help anyway. Michael Penn in his second channel Math Major has been covering some courses very well - I enjoyed his Abstract Algebra playlist. Recently, he started a new series in Topology.
